# SSL or own implementation?

Tags: c#, security, ssl, encryption, tcp

I have a client server application written in C#.
Actually the tcp connection is crypted by rsa and rijandel (like poor man ssl). I've often read, that I should use something like SSL not a own implementation. I know the reasons for this.
But if I use ssl, I'll need two certificates, one for the client and one for the server, right? (Because also the server sends some data to the client and other way) How I do this with the client? Or should I use for this communication an other crypting channel?

Comment: Only the server needs a certificate. Look at SSL-enabled websites. The server sends the page back to you (encrypted) and you can still decrypt it without needing your own certificate.

Comment: Okay then I've not understand ssl. I need two private keys and two public keys. The client has a private key and the server has a private key. If you say, only the server needs a certificate, what is the private key for the client? Is the private key from the client also in the certificate, for me make this no sense.

Comment: The key is derived using some math that is beyond my skill set. My understanding is that the key has certain mathematical properties that allow for certain tricky things to occur.

Comment: This question is better suited to security.stackexchange.com

Comment: With proliferation of MiTM tools, i would highly recommend using both TLS 1.2 (with client cert, server cert and cert pinning), and then slapping some sort of encryption inside the data that you transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL (or TLS) uses [public key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) for two purposes. One is to encrypt the communication channel (really just to exchange a symmetric key) and one for server identification. The public key of a public private key pair is exchanged in a certificate that is digitally signed by an authority.

If you do not need your clients to authenticate themselves (which is different from your users logging in), you do not need a client certificate. The server certificate is enough to identify the server and to encrypt the communication channel.

Client certificates are typically used in scenarios where background services or daemons need to identify themselves with web services. In that case, there is no user who's identity can be used to authorize the request.